# Converting Image From Colored to Grayscale

Tags: c++, image, colors

I've got an assignment that is centred around comparing native C++ algorithm speed to the counterpart implementations in CUDA. My question is rather simple, I suppose.

I need to find code in native C++ (or write a program) that converts an image from coloured to grayscale. My task is to benchmark the algorithm, rewrite it in CUDA and then compare the speeds.

I'm guessing this is just a 2D matrix, but I'm having a hard time tracking down an open source bit of code that I could use to benchmark. Where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for a grayscale algorithm.

```
struct ColorRGB8
{
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;

    ColorRGB8 toGrayScale()
    {
        ColorRGB8 ret;

        //Intensity Algorithm as per void_ptr's request
        char linearIntensity = (char)(0.2126f * r + 0.7512f * g + 0.0722 * b);
        ret.r = linearIntensity;
        ret.g = linearIntensity;
        ret.b = linearIntensity;
        return ret;
    }
};
```